# Type error: This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm developing webpage with Next JS.
In development environment, It is working well without anything error but when build in product environment, this error message is showing:
**Type error: This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided.**
My code is here:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
import { AiOutlineClose } from "react-icons/ai";
import Modal from "react-modal";
import styled from "styled-components";
import styledButton from "../button/styledButton";
import { ModalCloseButton } from "./ModalCloseButton";

interface ShowModalProps {
    text: string,
    children: React.ReactNode
}

const StyledModal = styled(Modal)`
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    padding: 5%;
    background-color: #555555;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-y: auto;
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        width: 40%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 5%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
`

export default function ShowModal({ text, children }: ShowModalProps) {
    const [modalIsOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    
    return (
        <>
            <styledButton text={text} handleModalState={setIsOpen} />
            <StyledModal
                isOpen={modalIsOpen}
                style={{
                    overlay: {
                        display: 'flex',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)',
                    }
                }}
                onRequestClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
                ariaHideApp={false}
                className="animate__animated animate__fadeIn"
            >
                <IconContext.Provider value={{
                    style: {
                        width: "100%",
                        height: "100%"
                    }
                }}>
                    <ModalCloseButton buttoncolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <AiOutlineClose onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)} />
                    </ModalCloseButton>
                </IconContext.Provider>
                <p>Modal</p>
                {children}
            </StyledModal>
        </>
    )
}
```

When modify children type like this:
**children: JSX.Element**
or
**children: JSX.Element|JSX.Element[]**

showing another error message like this:
**Type error: 'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component.

Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<{}, any, any> | null' is not a valid JSX element.

Type 'Component<{}, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.

Type 'Component<{}, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.

The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.

Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/runner/work/next-web/next-web/node_modules/@types/styled-components/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.

Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.**

How can I fix?

thanks!

add: **Product environment: aws**

Edit:

```
return (
<>
    <p>Click Button!</p>
    <ShowModal text="Next">
        <form onsubmit={onSubmit}>
            <input  
                type="text"  
                placeholder="write your first name"/>  
            <input  
                type="text"  
                placeholder="write your last name"/>  
            <button>submit</button>
        </form>
    </showModal>
</>
)
```

Comment: Which version of react are you on? This looks like a React 18 error with the `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.` error message.

Comment: I am now facing the same issue, and as @hellatan told above, I just updated React 17 to 18, which is suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you using `<ShowModal>`? It sounds like you are passing multiple children to `ShowModal`. You should be able to fix this by wrapping those components in a `<div>` or in empty angle brackets `<>` wherever you are passing them as props to `<ShowModal>`.

If you want to pass multiple children, you can do this by putting them into an array. For this solution, you should change your interface to be like this:

```
interface ShowModalProps {
    text: string;
    children: React.ReactNode|React.ReactNode[];
}
```

This means that `children` can be either a single ReactNode or an array of ReactNodes.

---

In the code you added showing your use of `<ShowModal>`, your closing tag looks like this:

```
</showModal>
```

You will need to capitalize it to match the opening tag, like this: `</ShowModal>`

Here is an example of your code working as expected with these changes [on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-sinoussi-6xi5bj?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: I'm sorry @Andrew Hulterstrom :(
Please check my question one more.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Andrew Hulterstrom but It is not working-_-

Comment: @ATRIIX-_- I just added a bit to my answer. Your closing tag on `<ShowModal>` seems to be wrong.

Comment: I saw that and I fixed `</ShowModal>`, but error is not disappear

Comment: @ATRIIX-_- Are you using `<ShowModal>` anywhere else in your code? I created an example on codesandbox using your code and it works fine: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-sinoussi-6xi5bj?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: yeah, It works well your sample code and in my development environment.  
but error is showed when **npm run build in product environment**.  
Is it product environment problem?

Comment: The same issue, it does not work in production when using `npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you try to display an array of JavaScript objects instead of React nodes. Instead of `<div>{myObjects}</div>`, use

```
<ol>
  {myObjects.map(({ name }) => (<li>{name}</li>))}
</ol>
```